# Connecting to parse server from https://example.com fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm trying to connect to the Parse server that is implemented in a VPS, from a website that served with apache.
The website is `https://example.com`, At first, when I tried to connect to parse server in Javascript codes, I did :

```
Parse.initialize("myAppId");
Parse.serverURL = 'http://ipOfVPS:1337/parse'
```

But I get mixed content: the page at '' was loaded over HTTPS .. error.

then I changed parse server Url in javascript to `https://ipOfVPS:1337/parse` and in the backend of parse server, I run the server with HTTPS. and now when I want to load the website of `https://example.com`, I get this error in chrome:

> net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID and this error in Firefox:
> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at.

I will be thankful if anybody helps me with this issue.

Here below I pasted my index.js:

```
// Example express application adding the parse-server module to expose Parse
// compatible API routes.

var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var path = require('path');

var databaseUri = process.env.DATABASE_URI || process.env.MONGODB_URI;

if (!databaseUri) {
  console.log('DATABASE_URI not specified, falling back to localhost.');
}


var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'XXXX',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'XXXX', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'https://localhost:1337/parse',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed

  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ["Message","Chats"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
  },
  push: {
    android: {
      apiKey: 'XXX'
    }
  }
});
// Client-keys like the javascript key or the .NET key are not necessary with parse-server
// If you wish you require them, you can set them as options in the initialization above:
// javascriptKey, restAPIKey, dotNetKey, clientKey
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem'),
requestCert: true,
//ca: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/ca.crt'),
rejectUnauthorized: false 
};

var app = express();

// Serve static assets from the /public folder
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

// Serve the Parse API on the /parse URL prefix
var mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/parse';
app.use(mountPath, api);

// Parse Server plays nicely with the rest of your web routes
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).send('I dream of being a website.  Please star the parse-server repo on GitHub!');
});

// There will be a test page available on the /test path of your server url
// Remove this before launching your app
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/test.html'));
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
var httpsServer = require('https').createServer(options,app);
httpsServer.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('parse-server-example running on port ' + port + '.');
});

// This will enable the Live Query real-time server
ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(httpsServer);
```

Comment: You need to include Cross-Origin Request Headers in your server. How are you deploying Parse Server?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo You mean you need to see my codes of index.js of parse server?

Comment: Your problem maybe related to the index.js. If you can share, I can take a look.

Comment: Dear @DaviMacêdo , I've edited my question and added index.js

Comment: Sorry for the initial wrong direction. I believe that your problem is actually related to the apache. Is it setup to accept https and also add / forward the cross-origin headers? Could you try to connect directly to the parse server (not passing through apache) so you can make sure?